# ¿Cuáles son los sonidos con el mayor grado de fuerza: las vocales o las consonantes?

Tags: pronunciación, fonología

Creo que son las vocales pero no estoy segura. Pienso eso, ya que, parafraseando, había leído en la Nueva gramática de la lengua española que las cuerdas vocales generan el sonido (RAE, 2009, 2011). Aunque, como dije anteriormente, no estoy completamente segura y sé que podría estar equivocada tanto en que sean las vocales como en la razón por la cual sean así (en caso de que verdaderamente sean las de mayor fuerza) por una mal comprensión lectora. Tampoco estoy segura de si el **conjunto** de todas las vocales tiene esa mayor intensidad en contraste con las consonantes.

Comment: You might get better responses on the Linguistic site unless you have reason to believe this would vary between languages.

Comment: @mdewey Yes, that's why I asked it on this section but I will try that, thank you for the advice.

Comment: No sabría cómo responder porque habría que definir qué significa exactamente "grado de fuerza". Si es solo la intensidad del sonido, es probable que haya algunas consonantes que tengan más intensidad que las vocales durante un muy corto período de tiempo. Si tienes curiosidad, puedes usar el programa Audacity para grabarte diciendo alguna palabra y ver la intensidad de cada letra.

Comment: @wimi Gracias por la recomendación. Cuando me refería a "grado de fuerza", me refería a cuáles suenan más fuertes. No sé si "intensidad" sea el término correcto, soy nueva en cuanto a la terminología fonética y fonológica.

Comment: No todas las letras suenan igual en todas las palabras. No todas las vocales tiene la misma intensidad y mucho menos las consonantes por lo que nunca se podría generalizar una respuesta. SI la respuesta existiera sería del tipo "las letras con mayor intensidad son a, e, o, k, b, p,"

Comment: Más que intensidad, creo que te estás refiriendo al concepto de escala de sonoridad (ver: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonority_hierarchy#Sonority_scale)